# Difference between File system created by fdisk and file system created by mkfs - linux

Tags: linux, partitioning, filesystems

I'm a little bit confused with partitioning the filesystem in Linux.

Please tell me the difference between creating the file system with fdisk and mkfs (when formatting the disk).

I can't clearly *tell* my problem, so please look at this picture:
[image]

Comment: Honestly, just use gparted and save yourself the confusion.

Comment: Well, there're so many tools that I can use to handle these problems. But here I just wanna understand a bit more about the inside =)))

Comment: In that case, you should've said that in your question. Currently it sounds you're having an issue setting up your partitions.. not that you want to understand whats going on. There is a difference.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Fdisk](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl8_fdisk.htm) partitions your hard drive.  It sets up partitions on the disk by creating a partition table.

[mkfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mkfs) formats the partition after it has been created.  It formats it based on a specific filesystem like NTFS, FAT32, Unix ext2 & ext2.

So fdisk isn't really creating a filesystem, it's setting up the hard drive so that a filesystem can be created on it.  I'm not sure I see a problem in your picture, did you not want NTFS?

Comment: So fdisk does not create the file system, right?
I use fdisk to create a partition with ext4, ext2,.. types
and I use mkfs.ntfs to format the disk.
I wonder, which is actually the file system? ext4 or ntfs?

Comment: NTFS is the filesystem.

Comment: @Hieusun2011: if you're familiar with DOS, mkfs in Linux is like FORMAT in DOS, and fdisk in Linux is like FDISK in DOS. If you're familiar with the Disk Mgmt tool in Windows, it has one GUI for both but partitioning a disk and formatting a partition are still separate steps there. The basic concepts are the same, and this was intentional, to support dual-booting.

Answer (score 15):

To use an analogy, think of fdisk as setting up the fences around your garden with small fences separating the areas that you want to have for grass, fruit trees and vegetables.  While it sets up these walls (partitons) for you it does not actually put anything in those spaces.

Then you use mkfs to format those areas into the ways that you are wanting, you choose your filesystem (be it grass, fruit or vegetable) and mkfs puts it all in place and makes it usable.

What you are seeing in "[partition type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_type)" is a legacy identifier that tells the system what type of operating system is likely to be able to read the contents, this is mainly so that an operating system such as Windows can quickly look at the partition type and (if it is a type it does not understand) then it can quickly move to the next partition to check that for filesystems.  This does not stop the operating system from going further and actually checking the filesystem itself to see if it *can* read it, it just gives the OS an idea what to expect.

You can still put a Windows [filesystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems) (NTFS) in a Linux (type 83) partition as you have done but whether or not any operating system chooses to read or ignore it is up to the designers of that operating system.

Comment: Does and can an operating system such as Windows only the partition type and not proceed further? If yes, does this mean that the contents would remain inaccessible until the partition type is updated?